# Why is my page freezing using a form filter

Tags: php

I have a filter setup on a form page that causes the page to freeze. There are two filters with checkboxes. As long as I only pick the checkboxes in one column it's fine. But as soon as I try to click on the checkbox in the other filter column, the page freezes. The code is below. Can anyone see anything that I got wrong?

```
<form class="filters" action="">

    <!-- <select name="orderby" id="orderby">
        <option value="date"> New To Old </option>
        <option value="title"> Alphabetical </option>

    </select> -->
    <div>
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="title" />
        <input type="hidden" name="order" value="ASC" /> -->

        <h4>Sections</h4>

        <?php 
            $sect = [
                // [ 'room' => '000', 'title' => 'All' ],
                [ 'room' => '1', 'title' => 'Up Stairs' ],
                [ 'room' => '23', 'title' => 'Down Stairs' ],
                [ 'room' => '347', 'title' => 'Basement' ],
            ];
            
            $room = [
                // [ "value" => 'All'      , "label" => 'All' ],
                [ "value" => 'Bathroom'  , "label" => 'bathroom' ],
                [ "value" => 'Closet'    , "label" => 'closet' ],
                [ "value" => 'Supplies', "label" => 'supplies' ],
            ];

            foreach($sects as $sect) : ?>
            
                <label>
                    <input class="section-checkbox"
                    <?php echo checked( 
                        isset($_GET['sections']) && in_array($sect["room"], $_GET['section']) );
                    
                    ?>
                    type="checkbox" name="sections[]" value="<?php echo $dept["room"];?>" />
                    <?php echo $dept["title"];?>
                </label>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

        <div>
        <h4>Room Types:</h4>


        <?php foreach($rooms as $room) : ?>
            
            <label>
                <input class="role-checkbox"
                <?php echo checked( 
                    isset($_GET['roles']) && in_array($room["value"], $_GET['rooms']) );
                
                ?>
                type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="<?php echo $role["value"];?>" />
                <?php echo $role["label"];?>
            </label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <hr />


        
        </form>
```

Comment: You seem to define `$sect` as well as `$room`, but later try to iterate over `$sects` and  `$rooms`. Also you check for `$_GET['sections']` later use `$_GET['section']`. There seems to be a lot of confusion about variable names.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you've defined **$sect** and **$room**, but you are using:

```
foreach($sects as $sect) 

foreach($rooms as $room)
```

Rather, you should use something like the following to do the iterations:

```
foreach($sect as $indsect) 

foreach($room as $indroom)
```

After that , you can use the $indsect and $indroom as arrays to further process what you want during the iterations.

Hence, the structure should be like:

```
<form class="filters" action="">

<div>
<h4>Sections</h4>
<?php 
            $sect = [
                [ 'room' => '1', 'title' => 'Up Stairs' ],
                [ 'room' => '23', 'title' => 'Down Stairs' ],
                [ 'room' => '347', 'title' => 'Basement' ],
            ];
            
            $room = [
                [ "value" => 'Bathroom'  , "label" => 'bathroom' ],
                [ "value" => 'Closet'    , "label" => 'closet' ],
                [ "value" => 'Supplies', "label" => 'supplies' ],
            ];

foreach($sect as $indsection) : ?>
<?php 
    /// do whatever you want in the iteration, like:
    echo $indsection['room']; 
    echo "<br>";
?>
            
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div>
<h4>Room Types:</h4>
<?php foreach($room as $indroom) : ?>
            
<?php 
    /// do whatever you want in the iteration, like:
    echo $indroom['value']; 
    echo "<br>";
?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
 
</div>
<br>
<hr />
</form>
```